# R: how to convert a matrix with each row as equal-length character string into a matrix of multiple columns?

Tags: string, r, split, character

I have a matrix with one column and many rows, each row is character string of equal length, it looks like by using the following code:

```
a = list("GTCA", "GACA")
library(plyr)
df <- ldply(a)
```

I want to convert it into a matrix with multiple columns, the number of columns equal the character string length. The wanted result should look like by executing the following code:

```
a = list(c("G","T","C","A"), c("G","A","C","A"))
library(plyr)
df <- ldply(a)
```

How can I do it in R? Thanks!

Comment: The term "list" is a distinctly different animal than "matrix"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ldply` form plyr:

```
library(plyr)
ldply(strsplit(df$V1,""))
 V1 V2 V3 V4
1  G  T  C  A
2  G  A  C  A
```

Comment: +1, using `fixed=TRUE` would speed things up (on bigger data).

Answer (score 5):

```
do.call(rbind, sapply(a, strsplit, "") )
#-------
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "G"  "T"  "C"  "A" 
[2,] "G"  "A"  "C"  "A"
```

You did say you wanted a matrix, right? If you wanted to do that with `plyr`-functions, then this succeeds:

```
 da <- laply(a, strsplit, split="")
 da
#---------    
     1   2   3   4  
[1,] "G" "T" "C" "A"
[2,] "G" "A" "C" "A"
```

And if you wanted a dataframe then use `ldply` with the same arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer from the [qdap package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qdap/index.html) but if you're not already using qdap the base solution would be optimal.

```
library(qdap)
colSplit(unlist(a), "")

##   X1 X2 X3 X4
## 1  G  T  C  A
## 2  G  A  C  A
```